# How do I make this into one activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing this tutorial, but I'm having some trouble with understanding how to make this into one activity. (In the tutorial, you would have Main Activity and Display Message Activity, but for my purposes, I need it to be in one activity) I understand how everything works, but I just can't figure out how to make this into one activity. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the tutorial I'm working on: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

And I'll include my code below, but it's probably easier to see where I am in the tutorial (I'm at the step, "Starting Another Activity").

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: but why you want it in one activity? you mean when you click a button you want a different layout?

Comment: Yes, I have to make the "hello world" app with one activity/fragments. :/ But yeah, I want a different layout when I click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the layout when a button is pressed and display `hello world` you can use your fragment `PlaceholderFragment` inside your `MainActivity` to display it

**sample:**

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView tx = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
        tx.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

In your `fragment_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/start_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So in the tutorial, at the "Starting Another Acitivity" step, where they make the "sendMessage" method, you know how they use "DisplayMessageActivity" there? If I only wanted one activity, how would I modify that?? Thanks.

Comment: @Karen you cant modify it to be one activity it would just lead you to nullpointer exception. So i would recommend using fragment as an alternative to activity.